# When to use article (a) and not using article , also using article (the)

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> Based on information from police report you are a traitor.
>   Based on information from the police report you are a traitor.
>   Based on information from a police report you are a traitor.

Which is right and which is wrong and what is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

> Based on information from police report you are a traitor.

Always wrong.

> Based on information from the police report you are a traitor.

Speaker/writer of this sentence expects you to know which police report he/she is talking/writing about.  You can't know this just from this sentence, there would have to be earlier sentences or conversation.

> Based on information from a police report you are a traitor.

Speaker/writer of this sentence does not expect you to know which police report he/she is talking/writing about.  The speaker/writer of this sentence is surprising you with this information.